# Providing feedback in a form using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to provide feedback to a user when they enter something into a textbox. A little tick if their input matches a RegEx and false if it does not.

What event do I need to use for this? Key up?

For example:

```
if (inputText.match(/regex/))
{
   document.write(input is correct); // or something else
}
```

I want to provide them feedback as they type. Something like what Yahoo [Registration does](https://edit.europe.yahoo.com/registration?.intl=uk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use "keypress", which is what's generated after a keyboard activity changes the input value. Thus, "keydown" or "keyup" would tell you that they pressed the backspace key, but "keypress" is what you get after the *result* of the backspace key.

Answer (score 0):

Use the onChange event to bind your validator.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('#foo');
var checkbox = document.getElementById('#bar');

elem.onchange = function() {
    if(elem.value.match('/regex/'))
        checkbox.class="valid";
    else
        checkbox.class="invalid";
}
```

Comment: It is customary to do it this way, you let the user enter the text and on change you validate.

Comment: @Nicklas A. - That's not what was asked for though.

Comment: It's not wrong, @Niklas A. but I think the question is about having the feedback be more "real time", so for example a user would know when they've chosen a long-enough username before leaving the field.

Comment: OP Wanted JQuery, not native JS syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to provide feedback as the user types, you are right - you can use the `keyup` (or `keypress` as has been noted in other answers) event:

```
$("#elementID").keyup(function() {
    //Your code
});
```

You could also use the `change` or `blur` events to validate the input when the user moves focus away from the element.